# Data Transfer Rate Calculation

Tags: nas, home-server

I'm looking into building a Network-Attached Storage (NAS) device out of an old laptop and extra storage. I'd like to understand what my maximum data transfer rate is out of it before taking on this project. I'm using a docking station to hold the storage, which connects to the laptop via USB 3.0, and my working computer connects to the laptop via USB 3.0:

**Docking Station (External Storage)** *--USB 3.0-->* **Laptop (NAS server)** *--USB 3.0-->* **Working Computer**

I'm using SATA 3 (6 Gbps) HDDs. Given this architecture, my bottlenecks are the USB 3.0 connections which have max transfer speeds of 5 Gbps. Applying the bottleneck and then after 8/10b encoding losses results in 5 Gbps x 8/10 = 4 Gbps = **500 MB/s**.

Is my data transfer rate 500 MB/s? Perhaps what makes more sense is that the 8/10b encoding losses occur at each point in the chain of data transfer:

**6 Gbps** x 8/10 = **4.8 Gbps** x 8/10 = **3.84 Gbps = 480 MB/s**

480 MB/s still seems too good to be true. Am I missing something here?

Comment: "*Am I missing something here?*" - Yes. You're trying to use the signaling rates on the wires as the data transfer rate. The problem is that the wires are not used 100% of the time to send file contents. There are SATA command requests that have to wait for responses from the drive. Those messages will be transported by USB commands and responses. Protocols simply cannot utilize 100% of the available link time. You're also not accounting for buffering, which will also reduce the apparent transfer rate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you are missing something - there is a bigger bottleneck - the HDD.  It varies from drive to drive, but if you can get 100 megabytes/sec from a hard drive you are doing fairly well - the speed will, of-course vary dramatically by brand and where on the disk you are.

You may be able to somewhat overcome this by some kind of RAID setup, but I would not really trust RAID on external drives.